# Prove or disprove $x^{a_1}y^{a_2}+x^{a_2}y^{a_1}\ge x^{b_1}y^{b_2}+x^{b_2}y^{b_1}$

Tags: inequality

> Prove or disprove:
>
> If $\max(a_1,a_2)\ge\max(b_1,b_2)$, then $$x^{a_1}y^{a_2}+x^{a_2}y^{a_1}\ge x^{b_1}y^{b_2}+x^{b_2}y^{b_1}$$

I can not understand it in the proof [Muirhead's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality)

#### Addition:

Muirhead's inequality.

**Proof.**

Case 1. Let $b_1 \ge a_2$. Then $\max(a_1,a_2)\ge\max(a_1+a_2-b_1,b_1)$ and $\max(a_1+a_2-b_1,a_3)\ge\max(b_2,b_3)$. Then
$$\sum_{sym}x^{a_1}y^{a_2}z^{a_3}=\sum_{cyc}z^{a^3}\left(x^{a_1}y^{a_2}+x^{a_2}y^{a_1}\right)\ge$$
$$\ge\sum_{cyc}z^{a^3}\left(x^{a_1+a_2-b_1}y^{b_1}+x^{b_1}y^{a_1+a_2-b_1}\right)\ge...$$

> Q.: Why $$\sum_{cyc}z^{a^3}\left(x^{a_1}y^{a_2}+x^{a_2}y^{a_1}\right)\ge \sum_{cyc}z^{a^3}\left(x^{a_1+a_2-b_1}y^{b_1}+x^{b_1}y^{a_1+a_2-b_1}\right)?$$

Comment: This looks like it would be false.  If $y = x$, then this reduces to $2x^{a_1 + a_2} \ge 2 x^{b_1 + b_2}$, which, if $x \ge 1$, is equivalent to $a_1 + a_2 \ge b_1 + b_2$.  However, the condition $\max(a_1, a_2) \ge \max(b_1, b_2)$ is not sufficient to guarantee this.  For a concrete counterexample, take $x = y = 2$ and $a_1 = 4, a_2 = 1, b_1 = b_2 = 3$.

Comment: (I think for Muirhead's inequality you also require $a_1 + a_2 = b_1 + b_2$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  http://www.mathsolympiad.org.nz/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/inequalities.pdf page 13 / No. 6 is your question answered.